# Master script calls helper scripts which calls C program, do not know how to get return value of C program

Tags: bash, scripting, c

I have a master script that calls a helper script like so:

```
 bash -ex $SOME_DIR/some_tester.sh
```

The helper script then calls a C program like so:

```
./some_tester_in_C
echo $?
.
.
.other functions called
```

The issue is that for starters I cannot get the return value from the C program.
The second issue is that nothing after my C program ends gets executed, the "other functions" do not get executed.

One important fact is the C program interacts with the serial ports and is printing things to the terminal. Once it is done talking to the external device it returns a value  that I need to capture in my helper script to proceed.

However, if I call the helper script directly from terminal without use of the master script it works fine, I get the return value of the C program and the rest of the code executes.

I tried to reproduce the problem by writing a simple script that calls another which then calls a simple C program and I can reproduce.

I have some `set +x`  here and there thinking this might be the issue but I do not believe so. I think perhaps the `$?` should be something else? But I am not well versed in Linux scripting. Some insight would be helpful.

Comment: `bash -e` will (essentially) cause the script to edit immediately after any command exits with a non-zero return value

Comment: @muru Wow!!! So simple!!! But ignorance is ignorance. Thank you so much it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you run the helper script with `bash -e`, you will set the `errexit` shell option in the script. This shell option will cause the script to terminate if a simple command (like your C command) terminates with a non-zero exit status.

If you want to capture the exit status from your C program, either make sure *not* to use `-e` when starting the helper script or run the program as part of a AND/OR-list (which avoids terminating the script even if `errexit` is set and the program exits with a non-zero exit status):

```bash
status=0
./some_tester_in_C || status=$?

printf 'Exit status = %s\n' "$status"
```